# How to match a row value and column value and return a matched cell as result in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, vlookup, excel-2016

I have a table with data distributed like in the picture below.

[image]

I would like to match each fruit vendor to the market only if they have a fruit.

[image] Something like this, Could someone please help me? I have managed to match the row and column successfully with  **IF and AND**. However, since some columns are missing values the match becomes ineffective. Please note that the columns and rows are already in place, only the correct fruit name is needed.

Comment: use iferror() to control for missing values.

Comment: Okay, but how can I match "Fruits vendor1" with the markets only to get the markets with fruit and ignore the rest of the markets?

Comment: I would try index() and match().

Comment: Added an answer - `=LET(MainTable,FILTER($B$1:$I$5,($A$1:$A$5="Fruits Vendor 1")+($A$1:$A$5="")), FILTER(MainTable,INDEX(MainTable,2)<>0))` then deleted after I saw the Excel 2016 tag.